# How to reload variable in while loop [Python] which reloads in background?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting one script in background. The only way to check if script was completed is to check log. Logs are updated each few seconds.

```
out = (os.system(comm)) #I get output of script which is running in background
outs = str(out) # convert it to string
print(type(outs.splitlines()[0])) # select only first line


while 'Job Status      : RUN OK (1)' not in outs:
    print ('Still running')
    sleep(2)
    # how I can get this 'outs' var in while loop be updated in each iteration - after 2 seconds
```

Generally how to updated iterated item which is in loop? - in my case it is `'outs'`

Comment: `os.system` does *not* return any kind of log or even stdout. It returns a status code. What are you trying to do? Read the process's stdout while it's still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just modify it after the sleep as follows

```
while 'Job Status      : RUN OK (1)' not in outs:
    print ('Still running')
    sleep(2)
    outs = str(os.system(comm)))
```

Note: os.system returns 0 if the execution is correct else some number. You might need to use Popen from Subprocess to get the outputs of a cmd line command run